# Ajax and php redirection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect, cross-domain

This is what I try to do:

1. server A display a page
2. javascript in this page call a server A php script with ajax
3. server A script check right and other data
4. if all is ok, server A redirect to resource on server B

Problem :

I cannot redirect my php answer to ajax, probably due to cross domain protection.

What can I do?

I don't want use `file_get_contents` because the resource on server B can be quite heavy so I don't want download it twice (once by serverA, second by client)

Comment: What about returning a url from server A, and doing the redirecting client-side?

Comment: i don't want redirect user, ajax request is used only for load protected resource, if i return url and do another ajax request for load, i have same probleme due to cross domain restriction

Answer (score 0):

just get a response from server which consists of js code to redirect you to the required URL

for example

```
echo "<script> window.location=url_to_redirect;</script> ";
```

Comment: Eh, no.
If you were actually loading the response as a page, that would work, but since the OP's using Ajax, he'd be better off returning the url alone, and handling the redirection in the ajax response handler.

Comment: ya he could do that too if returning a xml or json response....i have answred if it is a html response

Comment: i don't want redirect user, ajax request is used only for load protected resource, if i return url and do another ajax request for load, i have same probleme due to cross domain restriction

Comment: ok after complete validation just fetch the resource using curl or fsockopen and output it using a suitable MIME Type  or you could convert a resource let's assume it's a image convert it to data-URL and send as response

Comment: This mean download resource twice, once by server A, a second time by user. For heavy resource, it's a bit annoying

Comment: No Way why download twice?? it will be fetched only once data uri will not use your server once you send it to browser

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand how to do this without transit server B resource byte on server A

Comment: you should learn a little about php curl extension & data URI please go for it on google